# Can SANE daemon communicate with a remote network scanner?

Tags: sane

My understanding is that SANE is a service that sits between programs that perform scanning tasks and the physical scanner itself.
Also SANE provides an API to the programs that it then relays to the physical machine.
The typical setup seems to be where the scanner is connected directly to the computer, can SANE still communiate with the scanner and provide that same API when the scanner is located remotely over a network?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. There's a detailed guide describing the process here: `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial`.
You first have to make the scanner work locally any way.